# Автоматические определение типа данных у переменной при вводе

Tags: python, строки, int

У меня проблема, я должен вводить числа, пока не введу восклицательный знак:

```
c = 0
min1 = 0
max1 = 0
a = 0
while a != '!':
    a = input()
    int(a)
    if a <= 190 and a >= 150:
        c += 1
    if a < min1:
        min1 = a
    if a > max1:
        max1 = a
print(c)
print(min1, max1)
```

Проблема в том что питон выдает ошибку:

```
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '!'
```

Что мол, я не могу ввести знак, потому что у меня тип данных `int`
Как это решить?

Comment: Начнём с того, что строка `int(a)` ничего полезного не делает, потому что вы никуда не сохраняете её результат

Comment: Ты можешь ввести восклицательный знак (что успешно и делаешь). А вот компьютер не может конвертировать восклицательный знак в целое число, о чем и сообщает в ошибке.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
c = 0
min1 = 0
max1 = 0
a = input()
while a != '!':
    a = int(a)
    if a <= 190 and a >= 150:
        c += 1
    if a < min1:
        min1 = a
    if a > max1:
        max1 = a
    a = input()
print(c)
print(min1, max1)
```

Answer (score 1):

Как вариант: Конструкция try - except для обработки исключений...

```
c = 0
min1 = 0
max1 = 0
a = 0
while a != '!':
    a = input()
    try:
        b = int(a)
    except ValueError:
        if b <= 190 and b >= 150:
            c += 1
        if b < min1:
            min1 = b
        if b > max1:
            max1 = b
print(c)
print(min1, max1)
```

Comment: Неправильный вариант.